# Restlet throwing error when JSON begins with [

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, restlet

I'm using Restlet to consume a json webservice and I'm getting this error:

```
A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1
```

The json response I'm getting begins with a `[`, which seems to be causing the issue.

Is there a way to work around this?

Here is my code:

```
ClientResource resource = new ClientResource(
    "https://api.prosper.com/api/Listings?$top=3");
resource.setChallengeResponse(
    ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, "username", "password");
Representation representation = resource.get();
JsonRepresentation jsonRepresentation = new JsonRepresentation(representation);
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonRepresentation.getJsonObject();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json that starts with a `[` is a json array. Json that starts with `{` is a json object.

Use [`JsonRepresentation#getJsonArray()`](http://restlet.org/learn/javadocs/snapshot/jse/ext/org/restlet/ext/json/JsonRepresentation.html#getJsonArray%28%29)

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRepresentation.getJsonArray();
```

Before you continue, familiarize yourself with [the `json` format](http://www.json.org/).